# Take multiple urls in python using request.GET

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, list, django-rest-framework

I am trying to take multiple `URL`'s separated by comma and put them in list in python.

I tried:

```
url = request.GET.get('url').split(',')  #accept url seperated by comma
data= []
data.append(requests.get(url).content)
```

The above code did not work for obvious reasons.
How can I accept multiple url separated by comma using `request.GET`

Comment: `url` *is* your list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`url` is a *list* of URLs. Hence you can perform a mapping. For example with list comprehension:

```
urls = request.GET.get('url').split(',')
data = [requests.get(url).content for url in urls]
```

Answer (score 0):

To extend Willem's answer a step further, you can also do the same thing with a dictionary.
This is useful if you will want to use the url as a key to retrieve the content later.

```
urls = request.GET.get('url').split(',')
data = {url: requests.get(url).content for url in urls}
```